# Port model from Torch to Keras

Tags: deep-learning, keras, torch

I am trying to port the below model definition from Torch to Keras.

- Torch lua script

> ```
> local model = nn.Sequential();
> -- input 3x12x12
> model:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(3, 16, 3, 3))
> -- outputs 16x10x10
> model:add(nn.SpatialMaxPooling(3, 3, 2, 2))
> model:add(nn.ReLU())
> -- outputs 16x4x4
> model:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(16, 16, 4, 4))
> model:add(nn.ReLU())
> -- outputs 16x1x1
> model:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(16, 2, 1, 1))
> -- outputs 2x1x1
> model:add(nn.SpatialSoftMax())
> ```

https://github.com/IggyShone/fast_face_detector/blob/master/12net.lua

- Ported Keras - Python script

> ```
> model = Sequential()
> model.add(Convolution2D(16, 4, 4, input_shape=(3, 12, 12), border_mode='valid', subsample=(1, 1)))
> model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2)))
> model.add(Activation('relu'))
> model.add(Convolution2D(16, 4, 4, input_shape=(16, 4, 4), border_mode='valid', subsample=(1, 1), activation='relu'))
> model.add(Convolution2D(2, 1, 1, input_shape=(16, 1, 1), border_mode='valid', subsample=(1, 1), activation='softmax'))
> ```

But when I ran the ported script, the below error happened.

```
Exception: Cannot apply softmax to a tensor that is not 2D or 3D. Here, ndim=4
```

It seems keras does not allow apply softmax activation for Convolution layer. How should I do to pass this error? Thank you.

Comment: Does it work for your use-case if you flatten the output of your last conv layer into one long vector (using the Flatten() ) layer and then apply the softmax?

Comment: I tried and no error. Thanks :)